# Problem: Need to refresh pages for Polyfill.io to work

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, page-refresh, polyfills

The polyfills are working great at making my website works wit IE, but not on the first load. I need to refresh every pages every time to get Polyfill.io to works in IE 11. All you're supposed to need to get it to work is this script tag:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015"></script>
```

Pretty hard to recreate my problem with the snippet tool, so if you don't mind using my website to recreate it, it would be very appreciated.
[Link to my website](http://www.xaviergodbout.com)

Otherwise here's a video of what is happening.
[Video showing Polyfill.io needing a refresh on each page](https://youtu.be/2WYzxcPpDhM)

I am unfortunately not very familiar with this, but I feel so close to goal and also want my website to works in IE. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you [set IE=8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSBPS.png) in meta tag in your website. If I set document mode to 11 in F12 dev tools, the website can run well in IE 11:

[image]

So you could try to change `IE=8` into `IE=Edge` in meta tag, which means using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` and test again.

Comment: Wow! You're a life saver! The meta tag was indeed the problem.